# Get Label text with XCode UI Automation

Tags: ios, ios-ui-automation

I created a simple app where the user enters their name into a TextField, clicks a button, and then a label above the textField changes its text to "Hello **Name**!".

I'm trying to verify that this works correctly with a UI Automation Instrument. I am able to enter text and click a button but when I try to verify the labels new value it doesn't return the correct value. Here is the code,

```
var input = target.frontMostApp().mainWindow().textFields()["NameInput"];
var button = target.frontMostApp().mainWindow().buttons()["SubmitButton"];

input.setValue("Sonny");
button.tap();

// This is not returning the labels correct value!
var label = target.frontMostApp().mainWindow().elements()["HelloLabel"].value();

if(label != "Hi Sonny!") 
{
    UIALogger.logFail("The Hello Label did not have the correct value! "+label);
}
else
{
    UIALogger.logPass("The Hello Label was correct :D ");
}
```

I've tried using label() and value() but they both return the "HelloLabel".  Has anyone encountered this and found a solution to retrieve the labels updated value?

Here is the xcode code if its needed...

```
@IBOutlet weak var MyLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var MyName: UITextField!

@IBAction func sayHi(sender: AnyObject) {
    MyLabel.text = "Hi \(MyName.text)!"
}
```